# Install alongside "them"? Even though I only have 1 OS? Should I move forward? WIN7/UBU 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, partitioning

I am at a slight problem right now, and I have searched keywords on this forum, but I don't find anyone with the exact concern. While trying install 12.04 Lts on my machine as a dual boot option, ubuntu still says that I have multiple operating systems on it. It gives me the option to install alongside "THEM" (as opposed to install alongside Windows 7)
My NTSF reads as
SDA/1 SYSTEM 1.46 gib
500 used
999 unused
boot, diag

sda/2 is C:

SDA/3 HDDRECOVERY
13 gib total
13.15 used
HIDDEN

My concern is, Do I delete one of these partitions even though they are being Used? Do I shrink C: ? Or do I just move forward with "Install alongside them"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to "Install alongside them" safely.

The problem is that Ubuntu detects not only your Windows partition, but another partition (`sda3`) that it thinks contains an operating system. Actually, it contains a recovery utility installed by the PC manufacturer. The benefit from recovery partitions is that they are **usually** used for returning your laptop to "factory conditions", which means all pre-installed software and drivers will be taken care of; it restores the laptop to the state you bought it in. In my opinion, the "drivers" is the important part in recovery, but you can usually get those online from the vendor's website.

So, if you don't want the partition, it is safe to delete it. If you do keep it and install Ubuntu alongside Windows and it, you will probably find more than one "Windows" entry in your boot options later on, and selecting the option that points to that recovery partition will fail.

I recommend deleting the HDDRECOVERY partition (`sda3`) and moving forward, unless you need an easy way to recover the Windows operating system at some later date. You should not, however, delete `sda1`. Windows needs that to boot!

If you delete the partition and leave it as `unallocated`, the **Install Ubuntu alongside Windows** option will instruct Ubuntu to install itself in that `unallocated` space (that's how its designed; it looks for `unallocated` space, assuming that the user intentionally left that space for Ubuntu). You won't be prompted to set a size for the installation or choose a partition; it'll just use that `unallocated` space. If you want to specify a size for Ubuntu (let's say, you want more than 13.75 GB), then stretch the C drive to fill the `unallocated` space so there's no `unallocated` space left. Then, when you pick the **install alongside** option, it will give you a GUI prompt (a slider) to choose how big you want Ubuntu to be. You can do it the other way round too: shrink the C drive to have more unallocated space, and then choose the "install alongside" option, which will use all that unallocated space. I suggest doing it this way, but all of these options should work.

Comment: @Alaa Thanks! That's very helpful. I researched the net last night to find that the sda/3 was indeed the Toshiba recovery, like you said.  To answer your question: Yes Windows does refer to SDA/1 as "Active, recovery partition" and the sda/3 as Primary partition. Gparted refers to SDA/3 as HDD recovery, and sda/1 as boot, diag. That's where I got confused.  At this point, I'm considering deleting volume of SDA/3 through disk management on Windows 7, because I have Windows 7 installation and recovery on USB stick. I downloaded from DigitalRivers. Would that be a correct summation?

Comment: After deleting  13.75 GB Toshiba recovery partition, should I then stretch C: to fill unallocated space. OR, should I just move forward with Ubuntu install and let Ubuntu take care of that in installation process?

Comment: @Mike - having a conversation in comments is heavily frowned upon.  The  way we respond to an answer is to edit the question with additional details.  Please do so and remove your comments to tidy up

Comment: @searchfgold6789 - similar comment - please tidy up your comments, edit into your answer the relevant parts to answer the question.  thanks.

Comment: @Alaa I included some of that useful info in my answer but it wouldn't be in vain to produce another answer with some of the material in your comments above.

Comment: @searchfgold6789 since he accepted your answer, I guess there's no point in cluttering the question by posting another answer. If you think my edits are too much, you can roll back and let me know so I can post an answer.